# Testing Javascript Using Selenium

Tags: java, testing, selenium, web, web-testing

I am trying to test a website. I am able to access most web elements, except the menu items.

Basically there is a drop-down menu, I managed to click on the menu using Selenium, thus opening the drop down menu. Now I need to click on an element in the menu, but the menu seems to be written in Javascript, not as web elements, so I cannot find a way to access the menu items.

Any Ideas? I specifically need to do this in Selenium.

UPDATE: --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The menu on the website might be a context menu. It is opened using the left click. Any ideas how I can access its options?

Comment: Selenium RC interacts with browser using javascript, so you should be able to interact with those elements as well. Showing some HTML will be helpful.

Also, what have you tried till now?

Comment: I have tried various options, but haven't got anywhere regarding this issue. All I have managed to do was to access the elements of the menu by scrolling down to them using down and up arrow with selenium .sendkey() method

Comment: Which browser do you use? We had once simular problems in IE and Chrome.

Comment: I am using IE, since the website I'm testing only works on IE, and I have no other options since I am not it's developer, I am only testing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not managed to access the menu items using Selenium other than by clicking the menu, and scrolling through the items using up and down arrows through selenium.

I used OpenScript in order to record/playback the test, and it has worked. In my particular case, the website I was using required a flag to be set to make it testable. If you're encountering problems with testing a website, you might need to contact the developers and ask whether an "automation" flag has been set.

Answer (score 0):

The menu may be constructed and manipulated with the page's javascript, but it will exist as html. You can interact with this html using Selenium.

Comment: There is no HTML shown for the menu, upon selecting the menu button using developer tools, it just shows this:

<td id="File" noWrap="nowrap" ...etc>

And as a child, it simply shows:
Text - File

Answer (score 0):

```
 WebElement dropDownListBox = driver.findElement(By.id("Menu_id")); 
                  Select clickThis = new Select(dropDownListBox);                
                  clickThis.selectByVisibleText(activity); //If you know visible text
                //clickThis.getFirstSelectedOption();  // This will auto select first option in the drop down                
               // clickThis.selectByValue(1); //if you the value of drop down list items
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the tag is not a select tag but a td tag, so I'm getting an exception.

Under the "File" td, all there is is a javascript file as far as I can understand:

' <td id="File" noWrap="nowrap" style="border-bottom: #123783 1px solid; border-left: #123783 1px solid; padding-bottom: 3px; background-color: #123783; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; border-top: #123783 1px solid; border-right: #123783 1px solid; padding-top: 3px;" onmouseover="_JMenuBar_Select(0,0)" onmouseout="_JMenuBar_Unselect(0)" onclick="_JMenuBar_ShowMenu(0,0)"> '

Below that: 'Text - file'

Answer (score 0):

Opening a contextmenu isn't that easy.
Till now, I'm triggering an mouse-event via execution of a javascript (didn't find an other solution).
It's simular to that discussion:
[Trigger right-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6250447/trigger-right-click)
or
[Selenium 2 right-click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007153/selenium-2-right-click?rq=1)

Sometimes it's useful, if you are are just triggering the underlying js-function.
Most of the time the developer can give you one entrypoint to call.
This will give you the possibility to keep on building your tests and after some time you implemented the javascript function which opens the contextmenu via triggering the event.